# Pyspark: Mode formula with if error on multiple columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with 6 columns as below:

```
 MLP  Accuracy_MLP  XGB    Accuracy_XGB  RF     Accuracy_RF

3411    0.99199374  3411    0.935491304 3411    0.42968293

9518    0.99999988  9623    0.884243041 4567    0.686784383

9518    0.999999882 9518    0.957964659 2567    0.801463674
```

I want to add an extra column as '**RESULT**' which has the rule as below:

- Mode of MLP, XGB, RF column
- If error then take only RF column
- In excel the formula will be iferror(MODE.MULTI(MLP,XGB,RF), RF)

Result:

```
MLP     Accuracy_MLP    XGB  Accuracy_XGB   RF     Accuracy_RF  RESULT

3411    0.99199374    3411   0.935491304    3411    0.42968293  3411

9518    0.99999988    9623   0.884243041    4567    0.686784383 4567

9518    0.999999882   9518   0.957964659    2567    0.801463674 9518
```

List item

Answer (score 0):

There's no "IFERROR" in PySpark but you can handle several conditions with `when / otherwise` statement:

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/